# Challenge: what is the closed form of this function?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, number-theory, definite-integrals

I want to find the asymptotic expansion in $x_2$ of the following integral:

$$I = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty d\tau\ (x_1^2 + \tau^2)^n (x_2^2 + \tau^2)^{2-\nu-n} \log (x_2^2 + \tau^2)\tag{1}$$

with $x_1$, $x_2$ real, positive numbers, and $n\geq 0$, $\nu \geq 3$. I do not know how to compute this integral, and apparently Mathematica also not. Therefore I computed the integral for different values of $n$ and $\nu$, and tried to guess the form of the solution for all $\nu$ and $n$. At large $x_2$, I identified the following expression:

$$I \sim \lambda_{\nu,n} \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\log x_2^2}{(x_2^2)^{\nu-5/2}} \tag{2}$$

However I could not manage yet to determine a closed form for $\lambda_{\nu,n}$ yet. Here are some values for $\lambda_{\nu,n}$:

$$\begin{matrix} n & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \nu & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ \lambda_{\nu,m} & 2 & 1 & 3/4 & 5/8 & 35/64 & 63/128 \\ \hline n & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \nu & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ \lambda_{\nu,n} & 231/512 & 429/1024 & 6435/16384 & 12155/32768 \\ \hline n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\nu & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\ \lambda_{\nu,n} & 1/4 & 1/8 & 5/64 & 7/128 & 21/512 & 33/1024 \\ \hline n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \nu & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\ \lambda_{\nu,n} & 1/8 & 3/64 & 3/128 & 7/512 & 9/1024 & 99/16384 \\ \hline n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \nu & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 \\ \lambda_{\nu,n} & 5/64 & 3/128 & 5/512 & 5/1024 & 45/16384 & 55/32768 \end{matrix}$$

So the question is clear: what is the closed form of $\lambda_{\nu,m}$, if possible in terms of $\Gamma$ functions?

Here is a Mathematica script useful for quickly finding the numbers of the table above and more if needed:

```
\[Nu] = 4;
n = 1;
Integrate[(x2 + \[Tau]^2)^(2 - \[Nu] - n) (x1^2 + \[Tau]^2)^    n Log[x2^2 + \[Tau]^2], {\[Tau], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}];
Assuming[x2 > 0,   FullSimplify[Series[%, {x2, \[Infinity], \[Nu] - 2}]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From parity and by changing $\tau=x_2\sqrt{t}$ in the integral (assuming $x_2>0$), it comes
\begin{align}
 I &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty d\tau\ (x_1^2 + \tau^2)^n (x_2^2 + \tau^2)^{2-\nu-n} \log (x_2^2 + \tau^2)\tag{1}\\
  &=x_2^{5-2\nu}\int_0^\infty dt\,t^{-1/2}    \left(\frac{x_1^2}{x_2^2} + t\right)^n(1+t)^{2-\nu-n}\ln\left( x_2^2(1+t) \right)\\
 &=x_2^{5-2\nu}\left[\ln x_2^2\int_0^\infty dt\,t^{-1/2}    \left(\frac{x_1^2}{x_2^2} + t\right)^n(1+t)^{2-\nu-n}+\right.\\
&\hspace{3cm}\left.+\int_0^\infty dt\,t^{-1/2}    \left(\frac{x_1^2}{x_2^2} + t\right)^n(1+t)^{2-\nu-n}\ln\left( 1+t \right)
 \right]
\end{align}
For $x_2\to\infty$, both integrals become independent of $x_2$, the leading term is then the first one. Using the [integral representation of the Beta function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E3)
\begin{equation}
 \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{a-1}\mathrm{d}t}{(1+t)^{a+b}}=\mathrm{B}\left(a,b\right)
\end{equation} 
\begin{align}
 I&\sim x_2^{5-2\nu}\ln x_2^2\int_0^\infty t^{n-1/2}(1+t)^{2-\nu-n}\,dt\\
 &\sim  x_2^{5-2\nu}\ln x_2^2 B(n+\frac{1}{2},\nu-\frac{5}{2})
\end{align} 
which matches the given numerical estimations with 
\begin{equation}
 \lambda_{\nu,n}=\frac{2}{\pi}B(n+\frac{1}{2},\nu-\frac{5}{2})
\end{equation}

Comment: Amazing, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Higher order terms in $\left(x_1/x_2\right)^2$ could also be found.